# Strange "getter" behaviour in IE9 when accessing property of `Number.prototype` from a number literal

Tags: javascript, properties, internet-explorer-9, getter, prototype-programming

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'foo', {
  get: function () { return this }
})

console.log(10.5.foo)
console.log(10..foo)   // 0 in IE9!
console.log(10.0.foo)  // 0 in IE9!
console.log(10.01.foo)
console.log((10).foo)  // 0 in IE9!
var x = 10
console.log(x.foo)     // 0 in IE9!
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour and/or suggest a workaround?

[jsfiddle.net/yr7hQ/](http://jsfiddle.net/yr7hQ/)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why on earth would you *want* to do this?

Comment: Works with `new Number(10)` - only fails with integers as primitives. Nicely found!

Comment: It really does almost seem like an IE9 bug, but I'm curious as to the underlying reason.. There must be a better way of doing what you're after..

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Here's the source of all this deviousness: [mathmethods.js](https://bitbucket.org/davidchambers/mathmethods.js).

Comment: @davidchambers, the bug is present even on IE10 Preview, if you have some free time, I would encourage you to [report it](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE). Cheers.

Comment: Ah, figured it might be something like that.. Echoing pimvdb with nicely found then :)

Comment: @CMS: [Done](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/696145).

Comment: The [IE bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/696145) has just been closed as fixed: "This issue was resolved in Internet Explorer 10 Platform Preview 6 on Windows 8 Release Preview released on 5/31/2012."

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain that result, but you also asked for a workaround.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/FJ7Qx/

Script:

```
Number.prototype.foo = function() { return Number( this ) };

console.log(10.5.foo())
console.log(10..foo())
console.log(10.0.foo())
console.log(10.01.foo())
console.log((10).foo())
var x = 10
console.log(x.foo())
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm now kicking myself for not thinking to try this.

Comment: Oops. I shouldn't read code straight after getting off a plane. I didn't notice at first glance that `foo` is a method here, rather than a property. This is certainly an option, but I'm hoping to discover a workaround that doesn't require changing the API.

Comment: @davidchambers: "methods" are just properties that happen to have function type

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, but I'd like to be able to write `x.squared` rather than `x.squared()`.

Comment: What about `Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'foo', {
  get: function () { return new Number(this) }
})` ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid sullying the API, one could define a helper function in contexts where IE9 must be accommodated:

```
function _(n) { return new Number(n) }
```

This allows:

```
_(10).foo
```

I'd love to learn of a better workaround.